# Comment traduire ces termes reliés à l'agilité en gestion de projet: Product Owner, Scrum Master?

Tags: informatique

Je cherche à traduire la terminologie utilisée dans la gestion de projet selon Scrum.

Certaines traductions sont établies:

- *Daily Scrum* = Mêlée quotidienne
- *Grooming Session* = Session de raffinement
- *Product Backlog* = Carnet de produit

Mais je ne trouve rien d'évident pour les traduction des deux rôles principaux.

Pour le **Product Owner**, la traduction "Propriétaire de produit" m'apparaît être une traduction bête mot à mot et "Chef de produit" quant à elle fait davantage référence à "Product Manager" qui est un autre rôle selon certains guides de la méthodologie *Scrum*.

Et pour **Scrum Master**, je ne trouve rien que "Maître de mêlée", encore du mot à mot.

Pour info, le terme *Scrum* provient du Rugby ([Référence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(d%C3%A9veloppement)#Historique)).

Comment traduire ces deux rôles, si possible de le faire?

Comment: J'ai fait une recherche rapide sur internet. Pour *scream master*, j'ai trouvé les termes de *coordinateur* et *leader technique*.

Comment: Merci Damien, mais coordinateur est trop vague puisque le Scrum Master doit suivre un protocole précis, et leader technique non plus, puisque la solution technique doit venir de l'équipe, et non du Scrum Master...

Comment: Je rigole car... (je ne sais faire que cela...) et aussi cela me rappelle un souvenir vieux de pfff... 40 ans... quand Thomson avait dénommé le *product owner* : homme-produit. (Sérieux!) Nous nous étions demandé si il était le mari de la femme-objet... mais nous avions bien mauvaise langue à cette époque... Attention donc à la traduction... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**    
Il n'y a apparemment pas d'usage bien solide pour l'instant en ce qui concerne « product owner », comme le montre ce que l'on trouve sur cette [page web](https://www.icescrum.com/forums/topic/comment-appeler-le-product-owner-en-francais/).

Les termes suivants y sont proposés.

- **Pilote du produit**, **Leader du produit** / **Product leader**, **Guide du produit**, **stratège** / **stratégiste**

Certaines personnes ont une inspiration visant à introduire dans une traduction quelque chose de neuf ; deux termes reflètent ce point de vue.

- **sponsor fonctionnel**, **destinataire client**

Enfin, d'autres pensent que le terme anglais devrait être utilisé.

Cette dernière tendance est vérifiable dans le [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/Scrum+Product+Owner)
où on trouve la traduction « Scrum Product Owner » plusieurs fois. On y trouve aussi « **Responsable de produit Scrum** ».

Sur cette [page](https://www.elaee.com/2017/04/05/27570-fiche-metier-product-owner) peut être déduit le fait que seul « Product Owner » (aussi écrit « PO ») a été retenu dans certain cas.

[L'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(d%C3%A9veloppement)#Propri%C3%A9taire_du_produit) ne fait état que d'un seul terme, **propriétaire de produit**.

Les ngrams de Google ne donne aucune trace de « propriétaire de produit » ou de « Product Owner » et il n'est donc pas possible d'établir lequel des deux termes est utilisé le plus fréquemment.

**II**   « Scrum Master » est traduit par « **maitre de mêlée** » dans [l'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(d%C3%A9veloppement)#Ma%C3%AEtre_de_m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e). Il semble qu'il n'existe pas une variété de termes en ce qui concerne la traduction de « Scrum Master » ; cependant, on trouve de nombreux cas d'usage  où le terme anglais inchangé constitue le terme français (**Scrum Master**) ; en particulier toutes les traduction dans le [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/Scrum+Master) ne font  appel qu'à la forme anglaise pour traduire le concept.

Il n'y a pas d'information à partir des ngrams pour ces deux traductions non plus.

**III**  Pour savoir quels termes seraient préférables (selon la fréquence d'utilisation) il faudra attendre que par chance un spécialiste dans le domaine concerné lise la question. Il semble néanmoins qu'il n'est pas nécessaire d'être plus royaliste que le roi et que de choisir « Product Owner » et « Scrum Master » comme traductions ne devrait poser aucun problème.

Comment: Merci LPH, j'avais vu cette page auparavant et je ne voyais rien de vraiment emballant comme traductions, comme vous. J'assimilerais Pilote au Scrum Master plutôt qu'au Product Owner, Sponsor fonctionnel (quelle horreur) davantage au client et stratège, quoiqu'intéressant, m'inspire un contexte essentiellement marketing. Mais peut-être est-ce que je casse la tête pour rien et que je devrais, comme vous le suggérez, conserver les termes anglais!

Comment: @Brac L'expression correcte est « **se** casser la tête », donc il faut dire « peut-être que je me casse la tête pour rien ».

Comment: Haha! J'ai tapé trop vite!